# Вызов общей функции в вычисляемом поле СКД

Tags: 1с

Как в СКД в вычисляемом поле вызвать функцию из общего модуля?

```
&НаКлиентеНаСервере
Функция Кратко( текст )    Экспорт
    Возврат текст
КонецФункции
```

У модуля включены опции: глобальный, клиент, сервер, внешнее соединение, вызов сервера.

В вычисляемое поле пробую писать:

```
Кратко()
Вычислить( "Кратко()" )
ОбщийМодуль.Кратко()
Вычислить( "ОбщийМодуль.Кратко()" )
```

Во всех этих случаях при формировании отчета появляется ошибка, что «Функция не найдена»

Comment: Один из вариантов ответа: При программном формировании отчета на СКД нужно указывать в параметрах инициализации процессора СКД 4 параметр = Истина

Comment: Я видел это в поиске, но если честно- все пишут про это, но никто не может привести нормальный пример. Я на текущий момент изучаю 1с и не смог воспользоваться советами из поиска.

Comment: Тут http://novichok1c.ru/rabota-s-vneshnimi-naborami-dannyh-v-skd посмотрите

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Оформьте как ответ. Бред, конечно, что из-за этого приходится формировать отчет вручную, но весь 1с такой :(

Comment: @ReinRaus, у вас функция с параметром, а вызывать вы её пытаетесь без параметра (судя по приведённому коду). Может быть, в этом дело?

Comment: Не, чуть позже напишу в чём была проблема